# Can agora save the live streaming video and replay it inside the app.?

Tags: android, video, live-streaming, developer-tools, agora.io

```java
public class AgoraEventHandler extends IRtcEngineEventHandler {

    private ArrayList<EventHandler> mHandler = new ArrayList<>();


    @Override
    public void onNetworkQuality(int uid, int txQuality, int rxQuality) {
        for (EventHandler handler : mHandler) {
            handler.onNetworkQuality(uid, txQuality, rxQuality);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onRemoteVideoStats(RemoteVideoStats stats) {
        for (EventHandler handler : mHandler) {
            handler.onRemoteVideoStats(stats);
        }
    }

}
```

I got something like raw data saving but I want to know if that can help in saving the video on the server and replaying it.

Comment: did you solve the problem?

Answer (score 2):

You can save the videos locally in the app, but you need to access the low-level APIs in order to do that https://docs.agora.io/en/Interactive%20Broadcast/raw_data_video_android?platform=Android and create your own script to write all `videoFrame` to a file.

Alternatively, If you are looking for a cloud-based solution, Agora offers two solutions:

1.Cloud Recording: https://docs.agora.io/en/cloud-recording/product_cloud_recording%20?platform=Linux
2.On-premise Recording: https://docs.agora.io/en/Recording/product_recording?platform=Linux

Comment: This process can only allow us to record only one channel . Is there any way I can record all the streaming automatically ?

Comment: Which solution are you talking about, low level or cloud recording? @MithunSarkerShuvro

Comment: @Sai, for cloud recording, how to save the records for all channels ?

Comment: As far as I know, you need to send a REST request to stat the recording for each channel. However, there might a web hook that Agora might offer that you need to check with Agora support.  With  web hook you could automate the whole process. @IstiaqueAhmed

Comment: @Sai, if the channel names are dynamic in Flutter, then what should be done? Do I need to call the REST API from the web part or what ?

Comment: If the channel names are generated in client end and if you don't have a webhook setup form Agora, then you many need to send the REST request from you client for every channel. A best practise is to send the recording request to your server first and let your server maintain session and communicant with Agora Cloud Recording service. My answer might be a bit out dated, please reach out to Agora support to get the upto date techniques.